# If $F\subseteq K \subseteq J \subseteq L$, then $[L:F]=[F:K][K:J][J:L]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

It is a known theorem that if $F\subseteq K \subseteq L$ are fields, then $[L:F]=[F:K][K:L]$. This may be a stupid question, but can we say the same if we have $F\subseteq K \subseteq J \subseteq L$ be fields?

Comment: I think you mean $[K:F][J:K][L:J]$ on the RHS? The answer is yes and you can prove it from the $F \subseteq K \subseteq L$ base case by a simple induction. $[L:F] = [L:J][J:F]$ by the base case, now apply the base case again to $[J:F]$ to get $[L:F] = [L:J][J:K][K:F]$.

Comment: $F\subseteq K\subseteq L\implies [L:F]=[L:K][K:F]$ and $K\subseteq J\subseteq L\implies [L:K]=[L:J][J:K]$, so ...

Comment: @Bungo ah yes, sorry about that! For some reason I have a bad habit of writing them backwards :(